# SQLite3 Error: Could not find or load main class SQLiteJDBC

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to execute a SQLite statement in Java.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class SQLiteJDBC
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:courses.db");
c.setAutoCommit(false);
System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
} catch ( Exception e ) {
System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Table and records created successfully");
}
}
```

I saved it with the name SQLiteJDBC.java which is legit and saved the sqlite-jdbc.jar in the same file as the java file.
I am trying to execute as below:

```
javac SQLiteJDBC.java
java -classpath ".:sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2" SQLiteJDBC
```

And the execution ending up with the error: "Could not find or load main SQLiteJDBC"
I tried many a times and getting the same error. Can anyone help me out please..

Comment: Did you add the sqlite.jdbc.jar to the build path.

Comment: try .; instead of : it is simi colon